# I'm trying to run this command "bitbake-layers show-recipes"

Tags: yocto, bitbake, recipe

I'm trying to setup Yocto project in my linux system. I have added two layers which point outside the Yocto poky folder.

I'm following build steps from here:

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.7/brief-yoctoprojectqs/brief-yoctoprojectqs.html

I am trying to run the following command  "***bitbake-layers show-recipes 'ara-*'***"

I'm getting this error

**ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing /home/XXX/YYYYY/codebase/apd-source/meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/syslog-ng/syslog-ng_3.6.4.bb**

But I'm expecting output something like this:

***Parsing recipes..done.

**=== Matching recipes: ===**

**ara-com-examples:**

**meta-ara             1.0.0**

**ara-com-fusion-example:**

**meta-ara             1.0.0**

ara-com-gen:***

.
.
.
.
.

Comment: Before bitbake returns some results, it needs to compute some metadata stuff, and it fails to parse `syslog-ng` recipe, which is a fatal error. Did you modify this recipe?

Comment: No, I haven't modified that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error indicates bitabake failed to parse the recipe and could be due to syntax error from the recipe. But I have encounter this issue even without any error in my recipes. Honestly the don't know why that happened and that could be some issue with the build environment. Not sure.

In this situation, can you try

```
1. Remove the build directory and also ssttate cache directory.
2. Execute the setup environment script and rebuild
```

Try with the above steps and check issue resolved. And before that make sure you don't have any  syntax error in the syslog_ng recipe , check do you have any bbappend recieps for syslog_ng in your layer or any other layers and they don't have any syntax errors.